# Improve sqlite perfomance on iphone app

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I have a Sqlite database table having 200K+ records. The database size is 25+MB. I have done indexing on search fields.

To search a particular word with a like search ( SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM tbl WHERE name like 'something%' ) in SQLiteManager and in the iphone stimulator it take 0.2 - 0.3 seconds and in the device take little bit more. This is ok.

I just wanted to know is there any other DB than sqlite ( i have seen some apps use .pdb file ) which will make it much faster. Or is there any other way to handle large databases. ( like splitting the large tables in to several table etc )

Because in the next step i need to do complex searches. Actually I have done complex sql with combining two tables and the processing time is much higher ( 2 - 3 seconds in simulator and more than 4-5 seconds in the device )

**Addition :**
Ok so I have decided to use core-data. But here comes the next question. Pre-populating the core-data. I have search several links in stackoverflow and other places and even in CoreDataBook sample app from apple ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/ ) but all says copy it from one media to core-data ( xml, csv sqlite to core-data ) but in my case i have 25+MB database. If I do that then it will be 25+x2 MB. is there a way i can just populate the core-data manually ?

Ok populated the core-data db manually but result is same. ( there is a bil improvement but not enough ) So any ideas to handle this huge database in iPhone app with faster results ?

Comment: There is only one word solution for your problem and its core-data.

Comment: So Robin that mean if I port the sqlite db to core-data will that improve performance ? can you please give me a simple comparison of performance. if the performance differences are around 50% I will go for it.

Comment: You probably need to open another question for your addition because it's a separate issue. It's a common question. See this search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prepopulate+%5Bcore+data%5D

Comment: @TechZen you are right its a common question but my case is different because size of the DB file is much bigger and I have 200,000+ records in one table.

Comment: The size of the prepopulated store does not really matter, the solution is always the same: create a core data store file and include it in the app bundle.

Comment: @Viraj I am having a similar problem, did core data eventually help you with speed.  What was your eventual solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Viraj you can download this video of Brad Larson and see how he used core data do make his app Pi-Cubed faster and with less amount of coding.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/advanced-iphone-development/id407243028

its 7th video named 
"core data" and its free.

Comment: Ok so I have decided to use core-data. But here comes the next question. Pre-populating the core-data. I have search several links in stackoverflow and other places and even in CoreDataBook sample app from apple ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2  ) but all says copy it from one media to core-data ( xml, csv sqlite to core-data ) but in my case i have 25+MB database. If I do that then it will be 25+x2 MB. is there a way i can just populate the core-data manually ?

Comment: hey did you check that video, bard has just replaced the file that was generated from the code with the file he used in his mac application, so you just need to provide your sqlite file to the core data and everything will be taken care off.

Comment: yes I have checked and after so many hours try i managed to port it to core-data. its still get the same result. ( there is a improvement but its like say 5% improvement ) and additionally in my app folder ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/... there are two db files. One is inside the bundle and other one is in Documents. So app size is also increased. So Core-data doesn't seems to be the solution for my issue. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: did you use the functionality of core data like batch fetching and stuff, also you can delete one db file from the documents folder.

Comment: @robin let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1827/discussion-between-viraj-and-robin)

Comment: here are some of the code that I have used just to make a simple search.

NSFetchRequNSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
entityForName:@"WN_words" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lemma" ascending:YES]]];

NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lemma beginswith %@", self.searchBar.text];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];